# Switching Bootstrap active nav links with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to incorporate a jquery function to automatically change the active status of the `nav` links in my Bootsrap Navbar.  I have a base HTML file which extends into an app-specific base file.  That file is then extended to the individual pages navigated by the `navbar`.

Here is the app-specific HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/main.css' %}">
{% endblock css %}

{% block js %}
  <script>
    $(function() {
       $("#home-navs").click(function() {
          // remove classes from all
          $("#home-navs").removeClass("active");
          // add class to the one we clicked
          $(this).addClass("active");
       });
    });

  </script>
{% endblock js %}

{% block content %}
  <br>

  <div class="container status-update">
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="input-group-lg">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="What's new?">
        </div>
        <br style="height:20px">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="button">Post</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #6298bf">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="home-navs" href="{% url 'home' %}">Activity Feed</a>
          <a class="nav-link" id="home-navs" href="{% url 'vehicle-updates' %}">Vehicle Updates</a>
          <a class="nav-link" id="home-navs" href="/space.html">Garage Updates</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

And then I have this in the head of my primary `base.html` file:

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {% block css %}{% endblock css %}



    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% block js %}{% endblock js %}


    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
```

The page and links works just fine, I just can't get the `active` status on the `navbar` to change when I click the different links.  I don't know if I am referencing the items in the function wrong, or what.  Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ids for multiple dom elements. Use classes instead.

Try to change it to this:

```
  $(".nav-link").click(function() {
      // remove classes from all
      $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
      // add class to the one we clicked
      $(this).addClass("active");
   });
```

And if you want to scope it to only elements of a specific nav put the id in the nav itself and then use selector: `$("#main-nav .nav-link")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried your suggestion and I still can't get it to work.  It's weird, when I click one of the links it seems to bounce over to `active` status briefly before returning to the first default.  If I remove the default `active` status from the first link, nothing seems to change.  Not sure where to look next.  Could it have something to do with where the `script` is located?